# Undefined symbols in static library for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I am porting a static library project composed entirely of "C" files to iOS and when I try to use the library in an application I get a bunch of undefined symbols.

The problem appears to be name decoration. For example, let's say I have the function:

```
unsigned int hello_world(int arg1, int arg2);
```

When I use "nm" to look at the .a file I see the following:

For file1.c where the function is implemented:

```
0000002c T __Z10hello_worldii
```

For file2.c that calls the function:

```
U __Z10hello_worldii
```

But for file3.c that also calls the function and for which the symbol is undefined I get:

```
U _hello_world
```

All three **.c** files are in the library project. The prototype is in a header file that is included by both file2.c and file3.c. Are the **__Z10** and **ii** C++ name decorations? If so, why are these C files being compiled as C++?

EDIT:

Codo's question in regard to the "Compile Sources As" setting led me to try changing it to "C" from "According to File Type". This forced all files to be compiled as "C" and resolved the function name mangling problem but I still had 42 undefined symbols which almost all turned out to be variables. I noticed that there were no initializers for these variables so I added an initializer to one of them and when I rebuilt the project that uses the library, I only had 3 undefined symbols. It appears that adding just one initializer to a variable enabled the linker to resolve all references to that modules variables. The 3 remaining undefined symbols appear to be yet another problem(s).

EDIT2:

Of the 3 remaining errors, 1 was an uninitialized variable from another module and 2 were in-lined functions that needed to be declared static.

Comment: It indeed looks like C++ name mangling. So your C files were treated as C++ code. What does the file inspector in XCode say about the C files in the library project? Is the *File Type* set to *Default - C source*?

Comment: Inspector indicates File Type is "Default - C source" for all files.

Comment: In the build settings, section *Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Language*: Is it set to *According to File Type*?

Comment: @Codo It was set to "According to File Type", I changed it to "C" and it looks like that resolved the name mangling problem. I now have about half as many undefined symbols which I need to investigate since they are probably due to a different problem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Jim, just as a reminder - you ought to give Codo an up arrow on his comment, given that he fixed your problem.